# Styling non member class related functions

Tags: c++, class, styling

When it comes to defining your non member class related functions, should you typically have them in the header file or source file? Which is generally the best practice? Or is it all personal preference?

Answer (score 0):

Always try to minimize visibility. If you need your function only in the source file you can put it into an unnamed namespace:

```
// Your .cpp
namespace 
{
    void yourHelperFunction( void ) // only visible in the translation unit
    { 
    ...
    }
}
```

// 
I wanted to comment because I'm currently on my way home but I need a higher reputation... maybe I will refine my answer later.

Answer (score 0):

I generally choose one of four strategies for helper functions in C++, depending on re-use requirements.

## 1. Is the function large, and only used in one source file?

If this is a function that is only required in a single .cpp file, and it is going to be used in multiple places, put it into a anonymous namespace at the top of your .ccp file:

```
namespace
{
int myHelperFunc()
{
    int result = 0;
    ....
    return result;
}
}

...

bool MyClass::someMethod()
{
    return 0 != myHelperFunc();
}

void MyClass::someOtherMethod()
{
    if (0 == myHelperFunc())
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
           std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This allows re-use of the helper function, but avoids any potential naming conflicts.

**Advantages**

- Scope limited to a single file.
- No chance of naming conflicts with other helper functions in other files with the same name.

**Disadvantages**

- Large numbers of helper functions dropped at the top of a source file can pollute the file with functions of limited scope.

## 2. Does the function require access to class state?

If the helper function requires access to your internal class state, make it a private method.

```
int MyClass::myStatefulHelperFunc()
{
    int result = 0;

    if (IsInitialized())
    {
        ....
    }
    return result;
}

...

bool MyClass::someMethod()
{
    return 0 != myStatefulHelperFunc();
}

void MyClass::someOtherMethod()
{
    if (0 == myStatefulHelperFunc())
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
           std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**Advantages**

- Scope limited to a single class.
- Access to class state.
- Can be made virtual allowing derived classes to override the helper with an alternative implementation.

**Disadvantages**

- Must be declared in the header file.

## 3. Is the function helpful in multiple source files?

If the helper function might be used in multiple places in your codebase, extract it into it's own file inside it's own namespace:

```
HelperFunction.h

namespace ProjectHelpers
{

/**
 *  \brief  Do helpful thing.
 *
 *  \return a helpful integer.
 */
int myHelperFunc();

}
```

**Advantages**

- Easily accessible from anywhere in the codebase.

**Disadvantages**

- Large numbers of helper functions shared across multiple classes/translation units could be indicative of a code smell.

## 4. Is the helper function limited to a single function, and very small?

If the helper function is very small, and the usage is limited to a single function, you could create a lambda function and use it like you would any other function using the C++ algorithm function (e.g. `std::for_each()`).

**Advantages**

- Scope limited to a single function.
- Can be used in multiple places within the function by assigning to a variable.

**Disadvantages**

- C++11 and later only.

## 5. ... Other options

Other options for helper functions include static class functions and copy/pasting code. Each of the above strategies has it's own benefits and drawbacks as well, so it is up to you to decide the best approach for your own codebase.